# LDA Feature Importantance Extraction - sklearn Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, discriminant-analysis, importance

I have run LDA from sklearn on a dataset and I have gotten pretty good separation between classes. Typically I can extract feature importance to determine which contributing factor is most important. I cannot find this documented well for LDA.

Would anyone happen to know how to retrieve feature importance for Python sklearn ?

Comment: By LDA do you mean Linear Discriminant Analysis or Latent Dirichlet Allocation, or something else?

Comment: Also [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178792/how-to-use-lda-results-for-feature-selection) might be helpful